# Is it possible to use an Ubuntu Live CD and run GParted to partition a my HDD (including the partition that is usually mounted on a given system)?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, live-cd, gparted

I'm encountering a problem with my HDD's partitions and can't resize it. I've described my problem and my system here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/89427/gparted-0-3-encounters-problem-with-file-system-and-wont-resize-partition.

Now, from a more general perspective, I was thinking on whether it is possible to use an Ubuntu Live CD and use GParted in a live session to possibly go around that problem. Is that possible? I made a separate question as I'm interested in the possibility independently from my current problem.

You see, I only have one partition and that's mounted. When I use GParted through Ubuntu I don't get any error reports (unlike the case reported in the question linked above).

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Ederico are you trying to shrink your existing full-disk partition? If you are wanting to resize your existing installed partition you should really make sure you back up everything first. You can also go to the chat room for more help if you need it. Also, you can just use the Disk Utility in Ubuntu, you don't need Gparted unless you prefer it.

Comment: Yes I am, I do have backups and planned on doing one anyways. Thanks for the tip on the chat room. I'm used to GParted, though I'll give the Disk Utility a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you surely can..it is the easiest way to partition hard disks.
Here are instructions on how to do it with Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Please, note that, if you want to format, delete or resize a partition, the drive must be unmounted before doing it.

Comment: Thanks, so just to be clear, am I right in assuming that if I use a Live CD then the one and only partition, on my HDD which currently has my Ubuntu 11.10 partition on it, won't be mounted?

Comment: It shouldn't, unless you mount it by yourself or try to open a file or folder inside that partition; in this last case, the partition will be mounted automaically.

Answer (score 3):

It would also be possible to simply use the GParted Live CD as well.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

On my linux systems, I actually skip using the CD or USB and simply use the from Hard drive option. So long as you use the "To RAM" option on your boot line, the hard drive is completely re-arrangeable when you are in GParted's environment.