# Ubuntu is already installed in parallel to windows, how do I replace Windows entirely?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete Windows after an Ubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217133/how-do-i-delete-windows-after-an-ubuntu-install)

I have already installed Ubuntu in parallel to Windows 7 on my laptop. I now want to replace Windows 7 entirely. I have already tried to boot off of CD I made of Ubuntu 12.10, however the computer seems to go straight to the GNU GRUB screen (the screen that allows me to boot to Windows or Ubuntu). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ubuntu and Windows already installed in separate partitions (that is, *Ubuntu was not installed using Wubi*), I think it's just a matter of booting into Ubuntu and from there (1) reformat the Windows partition(s) using your filesystem of choice (ext4 for example) and (2) run `sudo update-grub` to automatically remove Windows from the GRUB list.

In your question, I don't understand why you're trying to boot from CD. If Ubuntu is already installed then there should be no need. Maybe I'm missing something?
Anyway, if the boot sequence goes straight to GRUB, it could be that:

- booting from CD is not enabled in your BIOS settings, or it's after the HDD in the sequence
- the CD is damaged

Answer (score 0):

İ'm sorry but windows is closed-source 
whatever i found link but you need a setup disk to repair

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

Comment: The question is about *replacing* Windows, not *repairing* it.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is with gparted from the Ubuntu Live CD. This question links to an answer:

[Is it possible to use an Ubuntu Live CD and run GParted to partition a my HDD (including the partition that is usually mounted on a given system)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89988/is-it-possible-to-use-an-ubuntu-live-cd-and-run-gparted-to-partition-a-my-hdd-i)

Basically the steps are:

1. Back Up everything
2. Boot with an Ubuntu Live CD
3. Run 'gparted' to edit partitions.
4. Delete the Windows partition
5. Resize your linux partition onto the new free space

There are some caveats here, listed on this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/OperatingSystemsAndPartitions

Mostly this involves making sure your boot loader (GRUB) can still find your operating system, but modern grub should work fine and find your Linux partition just fine.