# How do I delete Windows after an Ubuntu install?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-xp

I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to my Dell Dimension 4600 with Windows XP installed.  I now have a neat dual-boot system, but I want to get rid of the XP OS and keep Ubuntu as my only OS.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

back up your data and use instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

- Boot using the Ubuntu Live USB.
- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

- After the commands have run successfully, you'll see this:

[image]

- Choose the OS you want to remove and press OK.
- A confirmation window will appear:

[image]

- Click "Apply" to start the removal.

---

**Source:** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you DID NOT install Ubuntu using WUBI (Windows Ubuntu Installer) and you did it via the LiveCD, LiveDVD or LiveUSB (Live whatever), then follow this steps:

1. Open DASH and look for **Disks**

   [image]
2. Open the **Disks** utility and select the Hard Drive you want to use (Hard Drive selection is on the Left panel)

   [image]
3. After selecting the Hard drive, select the Partition you want to delete. Depending on the Disks version, you can right click the partition and choose DELETE, click on the Minus sign below the partition selection, click on a Cog above the partitions and choose DELETE. There are several ways of doing it. The only thing is that you need to have the partition UNMOUNTED and already have done ANY BACKUP you need from that partition before blowing it up into extinction.

   [image]
4. After you have deleted the partition you can create a new one (Learning curve for Disk is very low, very easy to use). The important part about step 4 is that you need to update grub so it notices that you no longer have Windows with you. So open up a terminal and type the following `sudo update-grub`:

   [image]

   It will say that it has detected X kernel versions but no Windows partitions. So the next time you boot the PC, no Windows partitions will appear.